# XSL-FO List label width

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

Is there a way to make the width of the list label more dynamic? For example... If I have a simple Arabic list (with only a few items), I don't really need much room for the label, so I can set my provisional-distance between-starts to be a small number.

```
  <fo:list-block provisional-label-separation="1mm" provisional-distance-between-starts="3.5mm">
     <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
           <fo:block font-size="9pt">1.</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
           <fo:block font-size="9pt">Text of the list item</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
     </fo:list-item>
     <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
           <fo:block font-size="9pt">2.</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
           <fo:block font-size="9pt">Text of the list item</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
     </fo:list-item>
  </fo:list-block>
```

However, if I have a roman list, I have to make the provisional-distance between-starts much larger to account for the size of the label, which could be many letters long

```
  <fo:list-block provisional-label-separation="1mm" provisional-distance-between-starts="6mm">
     <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
           <fo:block font-size="9pt">xii.</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
           <fo:block font-size="9pt">Text of the list item</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
     </fo:list-item>
     <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
           <fo:block font-size="9pt">xiii.</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
           <fo:block font-size="9pt">Text of the list item</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
     </fo:list-item>
  </fo:list-block>
```

I'd like the label to only take up as much room as it needs, depending on the label type and the number of items. Is there a dynamic solution in FO, or do I have to code my XSLT to account for the different combinations of label type and number of list items to assign provisional-distance-between-starts dynamically?

Comment: Use a table instead. If your fo processor supports dynamically setting column widths.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a table as @kevin-brown suggested -- e.g., you're using FOP, which doesn't do automatic table layout -- you can use the Print and Page Layout Community Group's extension functions for getting an area tree during the XSLT transform.

There's an example of sizing list item label width at http://www.w3.org/community/ppl/wiki/XSLTExtensions#Example_4_-_List_item_label_width:

[image: Two lists with list item label width set to exactly match formatted widths of labels.]

There's another example in the poster from Balisage 2014 at https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/2015/02/18/getting-an-area-tree-within-your-xslt-transform/, which also has an example of moving the list item body down to avoid a long list item label.

Answer (score 1):

I had been struggling with this too. The easiest solution is for me to use conditions for all possibilities. Only one thing I need is counting of preceding siblings. Here is what I use in attribute sets:

**for XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:attribute name="start-indent">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Counts *preceding* siblings, hence the 8 and le! -->
        <xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::item) &lt;= 8">
            <xsl:text>1em</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>1.4em</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
```

**for XSLT 2.0 and above**

```
<xsl:attribute name="start-indent">
    <xsl:value-of select="if (count(preceding-sibling::item) le 8) then '1em' else '1.4em'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Of course, it is necessary to use the same for long lists with hundreds of items and for nested lists as well.